# Getting error when try to save file in Asp.net Using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

This is the error i am getting right now

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+. at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)

i am using this same code on other website in same machine and there is no problem i really don't know what's going on please give me solution

here is my code

```
double newHeight = 0;
        double newWidth = 0;
        double scale = 0;

        //create new image object
        Bitmap curImage = new Bitmap(filePath);

        //Determine image scaling
        if (curImage.Height > curImage.Width)
        {
            scale = Convert.ToSingle(size) / curImage.Height;
        }
        else
        {
            scale = Convert.ToSingle(size) / curImage.Width;
        }
        if (scale < 0 || scale > 1) { scale = 1; }

        //New image dimension
        newHeight = Math.Floor(Convert.ToSingle(curImage.Height) * scale);
        newWidth = Math.Floor(Convert.ToSingle(curImage.Width) * scale);

        //Create new object image
        Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(curImage, Convert.ToInt32(newWidth), Convert.ToInt32(newHeight));
        Graphics imgDest = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
        imgDest.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        imgDest.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        imgDest.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        imgDest.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        ImageCodecInfo[] info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        EncoderParameters param = new EncoderParameters(1);
        param.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);

        //Draw the object image
        imgDest.DrawImage(curImage, 0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);

        //Save image file
        newImage.Save(saveFilePath, info[1], param);

        //Dispose the image objects
        curImage.Dispose();
        newImage.Dispose();
        imgDest.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have access to write to that path?  And the directory exists?

Comment: What exactly is your code doing here? Are you writing into a stream?

Comment: Is there an `InnerException` to the error?

Comment: my code is to get image from one driectory and save into other and but also do resize aswell

Comment: @JayZee we will need some code...

Comment: its big code let me update my question cant copy in comment

Comment: But i am using this same code on my other site and its working fine .. i made dll of my code and using it again .

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: I would check that the account it's running under can actually write to the save location.

Comment: i made a function an put all the code in that function and i am calling that function like this                                          ResizeImage1(600, item, Server.MapPath("~/Gallery/") + "/GalleryImage/" + newtable + "/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item));

Answer (score 2):

You will get a GDI error message if the account you're running under cannot save to the path at `saveFilePath` on this line:

```
newImage.Save(saveFilePath, info[1], param);
```

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: First verify this is your problem (you can try having it save a plain text file out to the same location.) Once you know that's the issue, you either need to run it under (or impersonate) a different account (one with the access), give the account it is running as access to that location, or save the file somewhere it already has access to. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dwc1xthy.aspx)

Comment: You can also look at the user the App Pool is running under (maybe Network Service) and give that user appropriate rights to the folder, rather than using impersonation.